# Get contents in irregular expressions in PHP

Tags: php, html

I have got a page content like this:

```
<table  width="100%" >
<!--Başla--><tr>
<td><a href="http://www.example.com/duyurular/2014/ekim/kutlama.html" class="duyuru1" target="_blank">&bull; Kutlama
<br /><span class="hmk">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Authority 28.10.2014</span></td></tr><tr><td><hr /></td></tr><!--Son--> 
<!--Başla--><tr>
<td><a href="http://www.example.com/duyurular/2014/ekim/genel-kurul.html" class="duyuru1" target="_blank">&bull; Genel Kurul
<br /><span class="hmk">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Authority 28.10.2014</span></td></tr><tr><td><hr /></td></tr><!--Son--> 
<!--Başla--><tr>
<td><a href="http://www.example.com/duyurular/2014/ekim/katilimci.pdf" class="duyuru1" target="_blank">&bull; Katılımcı
<br /><span class="hmk">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Authority 22.10.2014</span></td></tr><tr><td><hr /></td></tr><!--Son--> 
<!----duyuru başlangıc--->     
<tr >
<td ><div align="right"><a href="http://www.example.com/arsiv/duyuru/index.html" target="_blank" class="hmk"><span class="style1">Duyuru Arşivi</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a></div>
<!-- Güncel Duyurular Bitişi--> 
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I want to get `http://www.example.com/duyurular/2014/ekim/kutlama.html`, `http://www.example.com/duyurular/2014/ekim/genel-kurul.html`, `http://www.example.com/duyurular/2014/ekim/katilimci.pdf` links, `Kutlama`, `Genel Kurul`, `Katılımcı` link contents, `Authority` and `dates`. You see, there is no html standart.
I tried like this:

```
$html = file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/duyurular/duyuru.asp');
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$links = $dom->getElementsByTagName('a');
foreach ($links as $link){
    $exp = explode($link->textContent, '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; ');
    $bag[] = '<a href="'.$link->getAttribute('href').'">'.$exp[0].'</a> ( '.$exp[1].' )';
}
foreach ($bag as $d)
    echo $d.'<br />';
```

Of course, I did not manage. Could you help me?

Comment: Hint: `->textContent` is *never* with [HTML entities](http://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/charref).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some people don't like it, but regex is sometimes fine to extract stuff from HTML:

```php
if (preg_match_all('#"(https?:[^"]+)"[^&]+&bull;\s*([^<]+).+Authority ([\d.]+)#', $html, $matches)) {
  $urls = $matches[1];
  $labels = $matches[2];
  $dates = $matches[3];
}
```

`$matches` contains:

```
[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => http://www.example.com/duyurular/2014/ekim/kutlama.html
        [1] => http://www.example.com/duyurular/2014/ekim/genel-kurul.html
        [2] => http://www.example.com/duyurular/2014/ekim/katilimci.pdf
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => Kutlama

        [1] => Genel Kurul

        [2] => Katılımcı

    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [0] => 28.10.2014
        [1] => 28.10.2014
        [2] => 22.10.2014
    )
```

You might have to `trim()` all the results.

Comment: Thank you very much. But when I tried in my page, it returned error in UTF-8 like this: `Kat�l�mc� ( 22.10.2014 )`

Comment: Either your page isn't UTF-8, or you're reading the other website as not-UTF-8, or the website isn't UTF-8, or etc etc. UTF-8 everywhere all the time. Check the browser encoding setting (in Chrome: Menu > More tools > Encoding). Which is active?

Comment: Yes. Sorry. I have noticed yet. Other web page is encoded with `windows-1254`. My web site ise encoded with `UTF-8`. How can I solve the problem?

Comment: Eh, convert it? Teh internetz might help you with that. PHP has loads of encoding helpers. `utf8_encode()` **might** do it.

Comment: Yes I tried and googled. But when I use `utf8_encode`, It returns like this: `Katýlýmcý` and use `utf8_decode`, it returns `Kat?l?mc?`. So I asked whether `preg_match_all` has got any integrated function about this situatings or not.

Comment: But later, I understand that there is any integrated function, I tried `iconv('windows-1254', 'UTF-8//TRANSLIT', $matches[2][$i])`. It seems perfect.

Comment: But there is a problem too: When I try to get links, first link returns like this: `www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd`. The others are good formed. Is there any solution about it?

Comment: Start regexing at 200 chars in, so it skips the doctype. See the [preg_match_all docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) for that option. Or use `substr()` first.